# R - Order of the data table records from subsetting columns

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am currently learning data.table in R. a few questions which got me confused:

1. Does subsetting columns always preserve the order of records? (i.e. Row 1,2,3 will stay as Row 1,2,3 instead of Row 1,3,2)

   Also, does the same conclusion apply to different expressions, such as `DB[[1]], DB$V1`, etc.

2.
When subsetting multiple columns, I know I need to use something like `DB[,.(V1, V2)],` but I am confused about what's the result from `DB[,V1, V2]?`

The code runs, seems to produce the result but the rows are not in the same  order as the original table. If someone can explain what does the latter code mean, that would be great help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to start with small suggestion... if you create data processing related question on SO it is enormously better to ship reproducible code in the question, and expected output if it isn't clear. You will reach much bigger audience and gather more quality solutions. This is generally common practice on [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag.

1. Subsetting preserve order, underlying storage of data is column oriented unlike regular SQL db (which are not aware of row order), it works exactly the same as subsetting a vector in base R, just much faster.
   Regarding `[[` and `$`, these are just a methods for extracting column from `data.table`, and a `list` in general, you can use `DB[[1]]`, `DB[["V1"]]`, `DB$V1`. They behave differently depending if column/list element exists.
2. Third argument inside data.table `[` operator is `by` which expect columns to group by over, so you query column V1 grouped by V2, without using any aggregate function. And this is very different than `DB[, .(V1, V2)]` or `DB[, c("V1","V2"), with=FALSE]` or `DB[, list(V1,V2)]` or `DB[, .SD, .SDcols=c("V1","V2")]`, ... . Most of the api is borrowed from base R, functions like `subset()` or `with()`.

At the end I would recommend to go through [data.table vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), also there is my recent longish post that goes through various data.table examples: [Boost Your Data Munging with R](https://www.toptal.com/r/boost-your-data-munging-with-r).